# Gloudemans Cart content is empty when redirected to a view but is visible with dd()

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I want to redirect to the index view after an item is added to the cart. But **Cart::content** appears not set. I can return the content using **dd()**;

Here is the form in view:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['CartController@add', $account->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
{{ Form::hidden('product_id', $product->id) }}
{{ Form::hidden('product_name', $product->product_name) }}
{{ Form::hidden('price', $product->price) }}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/inventory/view-product/{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->id }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="/inventory/view-product/{{ $product->id }}">{{ ucwords($product->product_name) }}</a></td>
    <td><strong>{{ number_format($product->price, 2) }}</strong> per {{ ucwords($product->unit) }}</td>
    <td>{{ Form::number('qty', '1', ['style' => 'width:50px']) }}</td>
    <td>{{ Form::button('Add', ['type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'add', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}</td>
  </tr>
{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here are the **index** and **add** functions in the controller:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $account = Customer::find($id);
    $products = Product::all();
    $business_units = BusinessUnit::all();
    $cartItems = Cart::content();
    //dd($account);

    return view('cart.index')
         ->with('account', $account)
         ->with('products', $products)
         ->with('business_units', $business_units);
}

public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    //dd($request);
    $product_id = $request->input('product_id');
    $product_name = $request->input('product_name');
    $price = $request->input('price');
    $qty = $request->input('qty');
    $url = $request->input('url');

    Cart::add($product_id, $product_name, $qty, $price);

    $cartItems = Cart::content();
    //dd($cartItems);
    return redirect()->back()->with('cartItems', $cartItems);
}
```

I want to use a redirect because it has to go back to the index needs with the parameters for the search function.

This is how I am trying to access the contents of the Cart:

```
@if(isset($cartItems))
    @foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem)
      <tr>
        <td class="center">1</td>
        <td class="left strong">Jasmine Rice</td>
        <td class="left">Long-grain variety of fragrant rice.</td>
        <td class="right">99.99</td>
        <td class="center"><input type="number" value="1" style="width:50px"></td>
        <td class="right">₱2,499.75</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="text-center">No item selected</td>
    </tr>
@endif
```

It would yield "No item selected" but I again I am able to see the contents using **dd()**;

I hope you guys can help! **laravel**

Comment: It looks like you're not passing `cartItems` to the view? You're only passing `account`, `products` and `business_units'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you pass `cartItems` to your view in the `index()` method you should be able to see the cart items, because the updated data should be fetched again from the database (including the newly created items). There won't be a need to pass the `cartItems` along with the redirect then. I don't think the `with` method does anything after the `back()` method is called in any case.

So try:

```
$cartItems = Cart::content();

return view('cart.index')
     ->with('account', $account)
     ->with('products', $products)
     ->with('cartItems', $cartItems)
     ->with('business_units', $business_units);
```